# AngularMaterial mat-slide-toggle toogle working only for the first component

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I have an angular project I am developing using angular material for a slide toggle and text fields, and cdk drag and drop for drag and drop functionality. I am pretty new to angular libraries and angular in general.

I have run into an issue where the slide toggle is only toggling the first element inside an *ngFor loop. I have tried adding a let i = index to the ngFor and it is always passed as 0 no matter which toggle you select, however if I place {{ i }}, it will show up as the correct index. I am at a loss.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yezv9a

If you go to the project at that link, and toggle the test 2 or 3 toggle, it will shift the first 1 and I can not seem to figure out why

Any help is appreciated

Comment: here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yezv9a-49tqab?file=src/app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html

Comment: Ah, it was the id field being the same for all of them. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, There is one issue in your code is `mat-slide-toggle` element has an id which is repeating in `ngFor`

`<mat-slide-toggle id="toggle" color="primary" (change)="onToggle(button)" [checked]="button.enabled"></mat-slide-toggle>`

I removed the id attribute and found working correctly, based on my understanding you can find a fork of working example in below url

https://angular-yezv9a-bac1jz.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Hey, just ran into this issue and removing my id attribute does fix the issue. Could you maybe explain why this works. Why can't we set an id attribute on a toggle?

Answer (score 0):

Make the id attribute as empty

> 

Will work as expected